# Expand my class to get multiple users history

Tags: php, oop, class

I am trying to expand my class with a new function, i can already request a users history data but i now want to request multiple users at a time.

I do something similar already where i can request multiple users last position - see below

```
/**
 * Get last position of the user
 * @param mixed $user string/int user identificator
 * @return array associative array with these keys: status, timestamp, longitude, latitude
 */
public function getLastPosition($user) {
    $this->_checkLoggedIn(__METHOD__);

    $getLastPositionRequest = $this->_xml->getLastPositionRequest($this->application_id, $this->request_id, $user);
    $getLastPositionResponse = $this->_transport->request(self::PATH_LAST_LOCATION, $getLastPositionRequest);
    $return = $this->_xml->parseGetLastPositionResponse($getLastPositionResponse);

    $this->request_id++;

    $return['user_id'] = $user;

    return $return;
}

/**
 * Get mutiple positions at once
 * @param array $users associative array of users username => user id
 * @return array associative array of username => associative array with keys: status, timestamp, longitude, latitude
 */
public function getLastPositions($users)
{
    $return = array();
    $return1 = array();
    $i=0;

    foreach($users as $user => $id) {
        $u=new UsersData();
    $u->name=$user;
    $u->data=$this->getLastPosition($id);
        $return[$i] = $u;
        $i = $i + 1;
        //$return[$user]= $return1[$i];
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Here is my get history request, how can i run this to get the history data of multiple users at once?

```
public function getHistoryQuery($user, $start_time, $end_time)
{
    $this->_checkLoggedIn(__METHOD__);

    $historyQueryRequest = $this->_xml->getHistoryQueryRequest($this->application_id, $this->request_id, $user, $start_time, $end_time);
    $historyQueryResponse = $this->_transport->request('soap/gps/historyquery', $historyQueryRequest);
    $return = $this->_xml->parseHistoryQueryResponse($historyQueryResponse);

    $this->_request_id++;

    return $return;
}
```

Here is the parseHistoryQueryResponse function used in getHistoryQuery

```
/**
* Parse XML gps history response
*/
public function parseHistoryQueryResponse($historyQueryResponse)
{
    $match = array(
        'user' => 'User'
    );

    $x = $this->_match($match, $historyQueryResponse);

    $chunks = explode('</n:GpsData>', $historyQueryResponse);

    $match = array(
        'timestamp' => 'Timestamp',
        'longitude' => 'longitude',
        'latitude' => 'latitude'
    );

    $data = array();

    foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
        $tmp = $this->_match($match, $chunk);
        $tmp['timestamp'] = $tmp['timestamp'] / 1000;
        $tmp['longitude'] = $tmp['longitude'] / 1000000;
        $tmp['latitude'] = $tmp['latitude'] / 1000000;

        if ($tmp['timestamp'] > 0) {
            $data[] = $tmp;
        }
    }

    return array(
        'user' => $x['user'],
        'data' => $data
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you take the same approach you've already taken?

```
public function getMultipleHistories($users, $start_time, $end_time)
{
    $this->_checkLoggedIn(__METHOD__);

    $result = array();

    foreach($users as $user) {

        $historyQueryRequest = $this->_xml->getHistoryQueryRequest($this->application_id, $this->request_id, $user, $start_time, $end_time);
        $historyQueryResponse = $this->_transport->request('soap/gps/historyquery', $historyQueryRequest);
        $result[] = $this->_xml->parseHistoryQueryResponse($historyQueryResponse);

        $this->_request_id++;

    }


    return $result;
}
```